# Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error for struct member access in Python swig C wrapper

Tags: python, c, gcc, compiler-errors, swig

What is the error while compiling swig Python wrapper under GCC 4.8.2?

```
wfdb_python_wrap.c:3967:11: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
if (arg1->fname) free((char*)arg1->fname);
       ^
wfdb_python_wrap.c:3967:36: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
if (arg1->fname) free((char*)arg1->fname);
```

source code from `wfdb_python_wrap.c`:

```
...
#include <wfdb/wfdb.h>
...

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_WFDB_Siginfo_fname_set(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
...                                 
struct WFDB_Siginfo *arg1 = (struct WFDB_Siginfo *) 0 ;
...
if (arg1->fname) free((char*)arg1->fname);
...
```

header file `/usr/local/include/wfdb/wfdb.h`:

```
...
struct WFDB_siginfo {   /* signal information structure */
    char *fname;    /* filename of signal file */
    ...
};
...
```

Comment: Very strange code, but I guess that's SWIG being compatible with ancient compilers, or something. My advice would be to read the preprocessed version of `wfdb_python_wrap.c`. Perhaps the `struct` declaration is being hidden by preprocessor magic, or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare this type:

```
struct WFDB_siginfo
```

and use this one:

```
struct WFDB_Siginfo
```

which is different (note the uppercase S), so gcc truly believes struct WFDB_Siginfo is another type which has not been declared yet.

Comment: that was swig generated file I believe, let me check

Comment: there are also these declarations: `static swig_type_info _swigt__p_WFDB_Siginfo = {"_p_WFDB_Siginfo", "struct WFDB_Siginfo *|WFDB_Siginfo *", 0, 0, (void*)0, 0};`

Comment: so maybe your header is from another swig version?

Comment: `static swig_type_info *swig_type_initial[] = { ... &_swigt__p_WFDB_Siginfo, ...`

Comment: wfdb.h is from the C library, wfdb_python_wrap.c is generated by Swig I presume

Comment: `static swig_cast_info _swigc__p_WFDB_Siginfo[] = {  {&_swigt__p_WFDB_Siginfo, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}};`

Comment: `struct WFDB_siginfo *arg1` correction in first function `_wrap_WFDB_Siginfo_fname_set()` passed compilation, I wonder how Swig generated those lines incorrectly? I will try to correct the rest to see the result

Comment: have you been able to resolve this issue @ChesnokovYuriy ? I am running into the exact same problem under Ubuntu trusty64 with Anaconda Python 2.7 intalled.